# How to call stored procedure by Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to use Web API without Entity framework and calling stored procedure from Web API controllers?

Comment: You can - **of course** - use "raw" ADO.NET - `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` - and to map the results to an object type, I'd use **Dapper.NET** - or if you want to **really** write a whole lot of stupid, boring code yourself, you could also do the mapping from untyped rows and columns in your result set to your objects yourself - you decide....

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for your reply, Do you mean to convert data set to custom objects using Dapper? Is it reasonable to do this and does it have bad effect in the performance of an application?

Comment: As everything - going to a higher abstraction level (typed object instead of untyped rows/columns) **does** incur a performance cost - on the other hand, working with an object is just **that much nicer** and more productive for the developer...... but Dapper.NET is one of the best peforming micro-ORM's out there - it actually powers this very site here (Stackoverflow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, as the following sample:

```
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();            

            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetData", sqlConnection))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        dt.Load(reader);                        
                    }                    
                }
            }

            if ((dt == null) || (dt.Rows.Count == 0))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(dt);
        }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: this code use in aspp.net mvc and I want call stored procedure by Web API in asp.net web form

Comment: This code is in my project which is Asp.Net Web API 2